# Switch Images inside Fragment when Audio jack is connected or busy

Tags: android, android-fragments, audio

I am trying to detect if the headphone is plugged into Audio jack or not and based on that trying to change the image in the layout attached with a Fragment.

I was trying to learn about the Fragment life cycle on slidenerd video on youtube and honestly I couldn't understand a single word what he was trying to explain. As far as I understand something that was onCreateView Method runs only once when Fragment loads the UI elements for the first time.

Here, I have been changing the UI element based on the state of the Audio jack which is sort of dynamic updating of layout in real time.

Right now I am able to switch the images but the problem is that  I need to close the app or go to some other activity and come back to Fragment to see the changes. I understand why this happening, onCreateView runs only once.

Can anyone help me to with this?

second: I have the similar problem in other fragment where people list doesn't update even after adding a new entry to database until I go out of the activity and come back again.

**MeasureFragment.classs**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.kevin.sugar.R;

import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MeasureFragment extends Fragment{

    Handler handler;

    public MeasureFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.measure_layout, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.phone);
        IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
        Intent iStatus = getActivity().registerReceiver(null, iFilter);
        boolean isConnected = iStatus.getIntExtra("state",0) == 1;
        if(isConnected){
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.phone_connected);
            TextView button = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.start_button);
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }else{
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.phone_disconnected);
            TextView button = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.start_button);
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and it worked very well. Please if any of you have better solution than this then post here.

as far as I know it is working fine.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.kuro.bloodpressure.R;

import android.os.Handler;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MeasureFragment extends Fragment {

    ImageView img;
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);

    public MeasureFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.measure_layout, container, false);
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        return view;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }


    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void onResume() {
        getActivity().registerReceiver(bcReceived, intentFilter);
        super.onResume();
    }

    //
    private BroadcastReceiver bcReceived = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
//            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
                int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
                switch (state) {
                    case 0:
                        Log.d("TAG", "NOT CONNECTED");
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.phone_disconnected);
                        TextView button2 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.start_button);
                        button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Log.d("TAG", "CONNECTED");
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.phone_connected);
                        TextView button1 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.start_button);
                        button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Log.d("TAG", "CLICKED");
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.d("TAG", "I have no idea what the headset state is");
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(bcReceived);
        super.onPause();
    }


}
```